# Vlookup with wildcard not working (partial string match) on long values

Tags: excel, wildcard, vlookup

I understand the basic use of the `vlookup` with wildcard but I'm running into a problem lately.

I need to lookup a value that contained in a cell as a part of string. In the below Sample I look up colA in the colC, with should be found, then return the values in `col D` into `col B`.

I use `=VLOOKUP("*"&A1&"*",C$1:D$2,2,0)`, and it only works for `B1`.

Why do `B2` & `B3` don't work out the same way? Any solution?

Sample:

[image: Sample]

Comment: I found that if I delete the numbers after C335 in cell C2, then the function will work. I really don't know why.

Comment: It is not documented, as far as I know, but neither the `lookup_value` nor the single cell values within the `lookup_array` can be longer than 255 characters. This is related to `*LOOKUP` and also to `MATCH`.

Comment: In addition to the formula not working on long strings, even on shorter strings, your formula will return a result for partial matches.  In your example, if `A1:= R7`, then this will also return `a`

Comment: Thanks to Axel, that could be the reason. Also, thanks to Ron bring up this issue.

Answer (score 1):

As per your investigation and comment by Axel, VLOOKUP doesn't work with values over 255 characters in length. A workaround is use an array formula with the SEARCH function which handles much longer values. Double click into cell B1 and paste this formula, then save it by pressing `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER` instead of just pressing Enter by itself:

```
=INDEX($D$1:$D$2,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(A1&",",$C$1:$C$2&",")),0))
```

If you enter it correctly, selecting the cell will show {curly braces} around the formula and it should evaluate to your desired result.

This formula first creates an array searching for the position of A1 in every cell in C1:C2. The array will consist of numbers (when A1 is found) and errors (when A1 is not found).

ISNUMBER then creates an array of TRUE (when A1 is found) and FALSE (when A1 is not found)

MATCH then finds the first TRUE value in the array.

INDEX then returns the corresponding value from the D1:D2.

Edit: The formula now searched for the value in A1 followed by a comma. This ensures that an exact match is made. To also ensure that the formula can match against the last value in any cell in column C, a comma is also added to the end of the values in column C.

Comment: Note that with your formula, and the data posted by the OP, an entry such as `C1` in column `A` will return the result in `D`.

Comment: Thanks for you help Michael, and your explanation is also clear. After I tried your formula, it worked fine. However, Since Ron's first comment drew my attention, I found that the formula returns partial match, for example, if I change A1:= R7, it still return a. Is there a way to match exactly?

Comment: Hi Luke, I've updated the formula to also require a comma to be found after the value in column A. Note that it is not necessary to change the data in column C to end in a comma as this is also handled in the formula. The only requirement is that every value in column C ends in a comma (except for the last value in each cell). It doesn't matter if there is a space after the comma, but there must not be a space before the comma.